# Verify if a remote server is accessible

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to verify if a remote server is accessible or not?

I want to perform an open query on it, but before I would like to know if the server is online or not in order to generate a message.

Comment: Without further details, it's a little hard to know whether to answer this with 'Phone the DBA' or 'Ping the server on the command line' or 'Open a socket from your program'. When you say 'know if the server is online', do you mean you, or the program that you're writing.

Comment: Which programming language you are using

Comment: Open query gives error if it cannot connect. Is there anything else one need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even you check before execute your query it can be unavailable when you calling the method. So what you can do is try to process the task and catch the exception. you can show the message based on the exception.

If you want to check availability of SQL Server check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257084/whats-the-fastest-method-to-check-sql-server-availability).

Comment: Agreed. You *have* to write the code to cope with the server going down whilst the query is running *anyway*, why write more code than that?